# Wordpress pagination with Bootstrap 4 and Grid content Display

Tags: pagination

I'm new with wordpress and i have trouble need your help.

I writing a function to display a recent post in Grid style, but i got a problem with pagination. When i click on page 2 or 3, the url is change, but the content is not.

Here is my code for display

```
<?
  global $wp_query;
  $args=array(
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'posts_per_page' => 20
    );

  $my_query = null;
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

    $i = 0;
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  // modified to work with 3 columns
  // output an open <div>
  if($i % 4 == 0) { ?>
```

Here is my function for pagination

```
function bootstrap_four_get_posts_pagination( $args = '' ) {
```

global $wp_query;
  $pagination = '';

if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages > 1 ) :

```
$defaults = array(
  'total'     => isset( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) ? $wp_query->max_num_pages : 1,
  'current'   => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1,
  'type'      => 'array',
  'prev_text' => '&laquo;',
  'next_text' => '&raquo;',
);

$params = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

$paginate = paginate_links( $params );

if( $paginate ) :
  $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
  foreach( $paginate as $page ) :
    if( strpos( $page, 'current' ) ) :
      $pagination .= "<li class='active'>$page</li>";
    else :
      $pagination .= "<li>$page</li>";
    endif;
  endforeach;
  $pagination .= "</ul>";
endif;
```

endif;

return $pagination;
}

I stuck with this for 2 days, maybe some of you can help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have to change your query also have add

`'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' )`

So your new query should look like

```
 $args=array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),// add this line 
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'posts_per_page' => 20
);
```

For for information have a look at the [WP_QUERY Class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Don't forget it marked it as answer and up vote it :)
Glad to know it worked for you :D